# Not able to implement super and this keyword

Tags: java, compiler-errors

first class

> ```
> import java.io.*;
> class StudentClass
>  {
> String stdname;
> int stdno;
> String date;
> String phone;
>
>
> public StudentClass(String stdname,int stdno,String 
>  date,String phone)
>  {
>     this.stdname=stdname;
> this.stdno=stdno;
> this.date=date;
> this.phone=phone;
>    }
>
>  void display()
>  {
>
>            System.out.println("Student name: " 
>       +stdname);
>       System.out.println("Student no: " +stdno);
>       System.out.println("Date: " +date);
>       System.out.println("Phone: " +phone);
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> the second class inherited from first

> ```
>      class BookClass extends StudentClass
>      {
>    String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int 
> count;
>
> public BookClass(String Book,int issn,String 
>    author,int copy,int count,int Borrow)
>    {
>     super(stdname,stdno,date,phone);    this.Book= Book;
>  this.issn= issn;
>    this.author=author;
>    this.copy=copy;
>    }
>
>  void output()
>  {
>
>              System.out.println("Book Name: " 
>      +book);
>       System.out.println("ISSN: " +iss);
>       System.out.println("Author name: " 
>        +author);
>       System.out.println("No of copies: " +copy);
>             Int amount=500;
>             Double total;
>            if (borrow>2)
>            {
>             System.out.Println("Cannot Borrow");
>            }
>           else
>            {
>             System.out.Println("Can Borrow");
>            }
>       if(count==15)
>              {
>              total=amount*copy-1;
>              }
>              else
>             {
>             total=amount*copy;
>             }
>          System.out.println("Total: " +total);
>
>
>    }
>
>
>     
>
>   }
>
>         }
> ```

```
 class StudentReadingHabit extends BookClass 
{
   int r;
   StudentReadingHabit(int count,int Borrow)
  {
  super(count,Borrow);
  result=r;  
   }
void output()
{ 
           result=Borrow-count;
        
     if (result==8)
           {
            System.out.Println("Reading is good");
           }
          else
           {
            System.out.Println("Reading is average");
           }

         
       }


        }


 public class Cia_2
  {
  public static void main(String args[])throws 
   IOException
  {
 String stdname;
    int stdno;
  String date;
  String phone;
  String Book;
  int issn;
 String author;
  int copy;
  int count;

int n,j=0,ch;
do
{ 
InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);
System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t======Library======");
System.out.println("1.Enter Student details\n2. Borrow and Return details\n3.Reading Habit");
System.out.println("Please enter your choice:");
ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
switch(ch)
{
    case 1: 
    {
    
    System.out.println("\nEnter Student name:");
    stdname = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("\nEnter stdno:");
    stdno = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("\nEnter date of issue:");
    date=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("\nEnter Student Phone no");
    phone= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    StudentClass ob = new Bill(stdname,stdno,date,phone);
    ob.display();       
    }   
    break;
           case 2:
           {
           
            System.out.println("\nEnter Book name");
    book = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("\nEnter issn:");
    issn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("\nAuthor Name:");
    author=br.readLine();
             System.out.println("\nNo of copies: ");
     copy= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
              System.out.println("\nEnter Books Borrowed");
    borrow = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
           System.out.println("\nEnter Books returned:");
    count = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            BookClass ob2 = new BookClass(Book,issn,author,copy,count,Borrow);
    ob2.output();   

            }

            break;
            case 3:
            {
              System.out.println("\nEnter Books Borrowed");
    borrow = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
           System.out.println("\nEnter Books returned:");
    count = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
             StudentReadingHabit ob3 = new StudentReadingHabit(count,Borrow);
             ob3.output();  

             }
         case 4:break;
        default: System.out.println("\nWrong choice!!");
    }
    System.out.println("\nPress 1 to continue or 
   Press 3 to exit: ");
    ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }while(ch!=3);
}
}
```

The error has the following errors:

> ```
>   javac Cia_2.java
>    Cia_2.java:30: error: <identifier> expected
>     String Book,int issn,String author,intcopy,int count;
> ```

> ```
>    Cia_2.java:30: error: ';' expected
>   String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int 
>  count;
>                            ^
>   Cia_2.java:30: error: <identifier> expected
>    String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int     count;
>                                   ^    Cia_2.java:30: error: <identifier> expected
> String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int     count;
>                                    ^    Cia_2.java:30: error: <identifier> expected
> String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int 
> count;
>                                             ^    Cia_2.java:73: error: class, interface, enum, or 
> record expected
>   }
>   ^
> 6 errors
> ```

> The following code implements multilevel inheritance as well as the
> usage of the super keyword. The code should execute the following,
> thereby the errors. It would be great if the code could be debugged
> without changing the structure of the code.

Comment: Please format your code and add again for better readability. Thanks.

Comment: `String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int count;` This is invalid java code, you cannot declare multiple types as a single statement, you can have multiple variables of same type. Move all these to different statement (aka separated by ;)

Comment: @PradeepSimha where tho ,in the same class or main

Comment: As said by Pradeep, you need a `;` in between different variable type declerations. In short, on the third line of the second class above, replace `String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int count;` with `String Book; int issn; String author; int copy; int count;`

Comment: @sorifiend still more errors

Comment: @matrix Then edit your question to include the errors and changes, or ask a new one. Or better yet look up the error online to check for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`String Book,int issn,String author,int copy,int  count;` is invalid code and you seem to have multiple similar instances of this.

You cannot declare multiple variables of different types in a single statement. simply move all of these to different statements and the error should be gone.

Change that statement to the example shown below and the rest of the statements you've made like this and your errors should be gone.

```
String Book;
int issn;
String author;
int copy;
int count;
```

Comment: is it in the same class itself